# PreparedStatement SQL with optional parameters

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, prepared-statement

So I'm creating a search function, where the user can choose which fields to enter and the database will be queried based on those fields, ignoring the fields that aren't entered. Here's the code I'm using to try and achieve this:

```
    PreparedStatement ps = DeviceTracker.getConnection().prepareStatement("use SBK_CAPE_COOKIES SELECT * FROM \"CC_Employees\"" 
                                                                          +"WHERE EmployeeID LIKE ? AND FirstName LIKE ? AND Surname LIKE ? AND Email LIKE ? AND Region LIKE ? AND Department LIKE ?"
                                                                          ,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    if (!jTextField6.getText().isEmpty()) ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText()));
    else ps.setString(1, "'%'"); 
    if (!jTextField5.getText().isEmpty()) ps.setString(2, "'"+jTextField5.getText()+"'");
    else ps.setString(2, "'%'"); 
    if (!jTextField4.getText().isEmpty()) ps.setString(3, "'"+jTextField4.getText()+"'");
    else ps.setString(3, "'%'"); 
    if (!jTextField3.getText().isEmpty()) ps.setString(4, "'"+jTextField3.getText()+"'");
    else ps.setString(4, "'%'"); 
    if(!jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("All")) ps.setString(5, "'"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'");
    else ps.setString(5, "'%'"); 
    if(!jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("All")) ps.setString(6, "'"+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'");
    else ps.setString(6, "'%'"); 
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

The ResultSet 'rs' is empty every time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The values are set to '%' which is why LIKE is used. I don't leave any of them empty.

Comment: remove the singlequotes in your setString methods. They will automatically set by the prepared statement.

Comment: Well don't I feel stupid. That was the issue. Thank you kind sir.

Comment: The first parameter is an integer. Does some (your) database allow you to query integer columns with `LIKE '%'`? Or is the column actually a varchar column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the singlequotes in your setString methods. They will automatically set by the prepared statement.

```
 PreparedStatement ps = DeviceTracker.getConnection().prepareStatement("use SBK_CAPE_COOKIES SELECT * FROM \"CC_Employees\"" 
                                                                          +"WHERE EmployeeID LIKE ? AND FirstName LIKE ? AND Surname LIKE ? AND Email LIKE ? AND Region LIKE ? AND Department LIKE ?"
                                                                          ,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    if (!jTextField6.getText().isEmpty()) ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText()));
    else ps.setString(1, "%"); 
    if (!jTextField5.getText().isEmpty()) ps.setString(2, jTextField5.getText());
    else ps.setString(2, "%"); 
    if (!jTextField4.getText().isEmpty()) ps.setString(3, jTextField4.getText());
    else ps.setString(3, "%"); 
    if (!jTextField3.getText().isEmpty()) ps.setString(4, jTextField3.getText());
    else ps.setString(4, "%"); 
    if(!jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("All")) ps.setString(5, jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
    else ps.setString(5, "%"); 
    if(!jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().equals("All")) ps.setString(6, jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString());
    else ps.setString(6, "%"); 
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

the result of your statement is somithing like `WHERE EmployeeID LIKE '1' AND FirstName LIKE '''firstname'''`

But i think it is not a good design of your method. you should dynamicaly generate your query, so you add only the parameter which are used.

Comment: You're right, but that would take me a lot longer. It's not really going to slow it down any doing it this way. I have to write another search function that has a lot more parameters. Maybe I'll try your suggestion then.